# XSLT inheritance. Replacing HTML tags?

Tags: html, xslt, inheritance

Never did XSLT before. Is that possible to inherit a doc and replace just one  tag? If yes, can you provide any example please?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, and there are many many examples of how to do so on SO and elsewhere. The key concept to look up is the _identity template_ - a low priority template that just copies its input to output unchanged, which you can then override with more specific templates for anything you want to handle differently.

Comment: code example? Can I just mark single <td> tag and override it in child xslt doc? Or I have to repeaat a structure? Ian, any link ?

Comment: If you were learning Java, would you post a one-sentence question asking if it's possible to do subclassing, and ask for an example? I hope not. Learning concepts like this is much better done by reading tutorials and books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with the template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then you add templates for transforming the nodes you want to transform e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="td">
  <th>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </th>
<xsl:template>
```

transforms all `td` elements into `th` elements or

```
<xsl:template match="h6"/>
```

deletes all `h6` elements.

If you want to transform a single `td` then you need some way to identify it, assuming it has an `id` attribute use a match pattern like

```
<xsl:template match="td[@id = 'td1']">
  <td style="background-color: lightgreen;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

That sample sets the CSS `background-color` property of the particular `td` element.

Answer (score 0):

**This task is best handled with the most fundamental XSLT design pattern: using and overriding the [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**:

Let's have this XML document:

```
<root>
   <x>This is:</x>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c>hello</c>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>
         <c1>world</c1>
      </b>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>!</b>
   </a>
   <y>The End</y>
</root>
```

**The task is**:

1. Delete all `c` elements.
2. Rename any `b` element to `d`.
3. Insert a `c2` element after any `c1` element.

**The solution is amazingly short and simple**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c"/>

 <xsl:template match="b">
  <d><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></d>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c1">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <c2>xxx</c2>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the above XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <x>This is:</x>
   <a>
      <d/>
   </a>
   <a>
      <d>
         <c1>world</c1>
         <c2>xxx</c2>
      </d>
   </a>
   <a>
      <d>!</d>
   </a>
   <y>The End</y>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity template, when selected for execution, or called by name, copies the current node "as-is".
2. For each special task (deleting, inserting and renaming, we add a separate template that matches the required node and thus overrides the identity template, because of higher specificity.
3. The overriding, more specific template is chosen for execution on the nodes it matches and performes the task that we are required to carry out.